# Can I clean up an API fetch using variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fetching from an API and my code is so messy. I'm wondering if I can set a variable within .then() to clean it up?

```
    fetch.get(url)
.then(r => message.channel.send(`Win Rate: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.win_rate}\nLevel: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.level}\nPrestige: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.prestige}\nWins: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.wins}\nLosses: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.losses}\nGames: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.games}\nCompetitive Rank: ${r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.comprank}`));
```

Would be perfect if I could do something like this so I only have to have the massive chain of properties once:

```
var stats = r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats
```

That way I could do something like

```
stats.level
stats.prestige
```

Etc.

Also, I would like to refer to those objects outside of the function, what would be the best way to do that? I've considered saving to a .json file but not sure how to go about it or if that's the best way.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if I can set a variable within .then()

Of course you can, `then` takes any callback function!

```
fetch.get(url).then(r => {
  var stats = r.body.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats;
  return message.channel.send(`Win Rate: ${stats.win_rate}
Level: ${stats.level}
Prestige: ${stats.prestige}
Wins: ${stats.wins}
Losses: ${stats.losses}
Games: ${stats.games}
Competitive Rank: ${stats.comprank}`);
});
```

Also notice that template literals support linebreaks.

> Also, I would like to refer to those objects outside of the function

No, the values are only available asynchronously within the promise callback. Of course, you can store the promise in a variable and attach as many `then` callbacks as you want, whenever you want.